# Project including dictionary, loops, user input and factorial

Tags: python

I am writing a program in order to determine what are the probability of 2 songs of a same album playing back to back in a shuffled playlist.

For that I will be using the functions listed in the title:

- User input (to make it interactive with a user)
- for loop (to have the user add as many values as needed)
- dictionary (to store the user's input and add maths to it later)
- Factorial (to transform each user input into a percentage related to the total of songs in such playlist)

My issue is that I do not know how to structure my code: I have been doing good with the user input phase, but to add those imputed values into a dictionary is where I'm stuck. All the solutions online are provided for a dictionary alone and not in complement or addition of a for loop.

Here is my code:

```
import math
import statistics

print("\n Hey user! this bot has for purpose to tell you the probability of \n
playing a song of the same album in a shuffled playlist. \n")
total_songs = int(input("\n Enter the total of your songs:"))

lst = []
num = int(input('Enter a number of albums: '))
for n in range(num):
    numbers = int(input('Enter number of song for each album: '))
    lst.append(numbers)
print("Sum of songs belonging to an album is :", sum(lst))
print(lst)

print("\nLet's find out the songs that don't belong to any album. This will be handy later:")

solo_songs = total_songs - sum(lst)
print(int(solo_songs))


print("Nice! Now we need to find out the probabilities of 2 songs of the same album playing back to back in shuffle mode")

#Each album needs to be considered 1 entity and to that, the solo_songs value needs to be multiplied by itself -1 until 0
#to respect the probability formula
```

I do not know where to put my dictionary block, before or after my loop? How to add the user inputs into the dictionary simply?

Answer (score 0):

That's more like a mathematical problem.

You have `n` songs, they have `n!` possible shufflings.

However if you pick songs `a` and `b`, they as a pair `ab` can appear in `n-1` positions, while the other `n-2` songs can be "poured" around them in `(n-2)!` possible shufflings.

Like `n=5`:

```
ab xyz  - where xyz has 3! shufflings
x ab yz - where xyz still has 3! shufflings
xy ab z - where xyz still has 3! shufflings
xyz ab  - where xyz still has 3! shufflings
```

so it's `(n-1)*(n-2)!`. If you need `ba` pairings too, multiply that by 2.
And for probability, divide it by `n!`, and of course as there is a `!` in both parts, you can actually eliminate them:

```
(n-1) * (n-2)! / n! = (n-1)/(n*(n-1)) = 1/n
```

(or `2/n` if `ba`s count too)

I don't know how to organize your code either.